# Is the dual of a unitary operator on a Hilbert space always a continous linear operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, dual-spaces

I have encountered this in a course (not functional analysis), but I am wondering whether this is a general fact.

Thank you very much in advance for any input!

Comment: The dual (adjoint) of any bounded linear operator is a bounded linear operator.